# Can foxpro Dos application runs in Ubuntu

Tags: ms-dos

My business application is build with Foxpro DOS and runs in LAN with 5 computers. I want to know this application can run in Ubuntu?

For my printing requirement, I use a third party application "DOS2USB" for transferring printing job from LPT1 to Laser printers as my application send printing job on LPT1. I also want to know that the same application can be run in Ubuntu for transferring printing job from LPT1 to Usb Printer?

Thanks and hope to get answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try [DOSEMU](http://www.dosemu.org/) (package `dosemu`, not installed by default).

As far as I know DOSEMU can redirect print jobs from LPT to the Linux printer spooler so you probably don't need DOS2USB